# Перемещение кнопки вправо и влево

Tags: android, android-button

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы я мог подвинуть ImageButton только по оси x вправо. При достижении определённых координат я уже не смогу подвинуть ImageButton вправо, но смогу подвинуть влево. Помогите пожалуйста!
Будут какие вопросы - обязательно пишите в комментарии.
ImageButton:

```
private void potatoFunc() {
    RelativeLayout mainLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainmain);
    ImageView imageView = new ImageButton(Main2Activity.this);
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.potato);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams imageViewLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(450, 150);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(imageViewLayoutParams);
    imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    imageViewLayoutParams.setMargins(15,10,0,0);
    imageView.setId(Integer.parseInt("25"));


    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent int46 = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, potato.class);
            startActivity(int46);
        }
    });


    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putInt("int", 25);
    editor.apply();

    mainLayout.addView(imageView);
}
```

SharedPreferences нужен для того, чтобы кнопка оставалась на Acitivty.

Comment: Что именно не получается?

Comment: @АндроидАндроид Я не знаю, как сделать так, чтобы я мог перемещать кнопку только по оси x, и при достижении определённых координат, она больше не могла двигаться вправо, но могла двигаться влево. Я хочу, чтобы мне подсказали, как это сделать

Comment: @АндроидАндроид Я был бы рад, если бы вы мне помогли с решением данного вопроса

Comment: Здесь нужен EventListener для считывания координат пальца и Animator или setX в EL

Comment: вот пример https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2010/06/making-sense-of-multitouch.html

Comment: @ОлегКотенко Хорошо, не могли бы вы написать, как это сделать? Я дополню свой вопрос.

Comment: @Александр зделано. Все что в вашем onClickListener-e перекиньте в eventListener(там где тост), уберите скорее всего обработку Y оси и X ограничьте в указанном коментарием месте

Comment: @ОлегКотенко Да, работает, только я не знаю, как поставить ограничения. Я новичок :)

Comment: @ОлегКотенко Ограничение по оси y я сделал, просто удалив строчку view.setY(event.getRawY() + dY);

Comment: @ОлегКотенко Может сделать так: делаем проверку, которая определит, если кнопка стоит в определённых координатах, то это правда. В ACTION_MOVE написать, если проверка является правдой, то ACTION_MOVE останавливается. Как-то так

Comment: Ну да,"уберите скорее всего обработку Y", а насчет ограничения то банально if(event.getRawX()+dX<limitX){view.setX(event.getRawX() + dX)}else{//или break; или продолжать слушать перетягивание и просто не создавать блок else}  но if расточительно использовать, я попробовал искать что-то легче..пока ничего

Comment: @ОлегКотенко Пытаюсь получить координаты при нажатии на кнопку:  
Integer one = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(dX));    
Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, one, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
Но вылетает приложение

Comment: @Александр там не int а float

Comment: а зачем float в string в int? можно ж сразу в int, хотя координаты лучше хранить в float\double

Comment: @ОлегКотенко Переделал. Такая штука. При нажатии, отображается, в каких координатах я нажал на кнопку. Как мне узнать, в каких координатах изначально стоит кнопка (глобально, по отношению к Activity)?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84002/discussion-between---and-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот минимальный вариант с возможностью различить клик от перетаскивания

```
public class DraggableView extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnTouchListener 
{
  float dX;
  float dY;
  int lastAction;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.draggable_view);
      //View, которая будет перемещаться
      final View dragView = findViewById(R.id.draggable_view);      
      dragView.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    //слушатель событий прикосновений(ActionDown - палец на экране/
                                      ActionMove - движение пальца по экрану/
                                      ActionUP - палец убран)
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
      switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
          dX = view.getX() - event.getRawX();
          dY = view.getY() - event.getRawY();
          lastAction = MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN;
          break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
          //здесь задаются ограничения по движение view
          view.setY(event.getRawY() + dY);
          view.setX(event.getRawX() + dX);
          lastAction = MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE;
          break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
          if (lastAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            Toast.makeText(DraggableView.this, "Clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          break;

  default:
    return false;
}
return true;
    }
  }
```